# Can I use Ubuntu to reinstall Windows from a recovery disk?

Tags: installation, windows, data-recovery

I have a laptop that won't boot into Windows 7 64-bit due to a bad update.  It also won't boot from the recovery disk.  I can get into the setup options.  If I install Ubuntu from the Live Disk, can I use this to reinstall Windows from the recovery disk?

Comment: Do you have an OEM recovery partition on the hard drive?  You can use grub to boot into the OEM recovery partition.

Comment: Hi, I do not know the answer to this.  I can get into the F2 setup options, can I find out from there?

Comment: No, not usually.  If you look in the laptop manual under recovery options it will tell you how to boot into the recovery partition, if it has one.  You don't *really* need grub to do this. Usually, OEMs will either give you installation disks with the computer, or you will have a recovery partition on the hard drive.

Comment: Thank you, I think my hard drive is bad.  I used a USB stick to run Ubuntu and I can't install it, the hard drive won't mount and neither does the DVD drive.  They show up, but won't open or mount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another large USB pendrive to install Ubuntu to, and this will get your laptop working again.  You will just have to boot off the installed pendrive and run off that.  If you have something like an SD card reader in the laptop you can also do the same thing for a large SD card.

In the long term you can get the hard drive in the laptop replaced and you will be able to install Ubuntu to the hard drive, which will boot and run much faster than the USB pendrive.  It sounds like you may need to have the optical drive replaced as well.

If you want you can approach the OEM who manufactured your laptop and ask for a set of Windows installation disks for your laptop.  You will need to provide them with the full model number off the label on the bottome (not just the general model number) and they may charge you a fee for providing and shipping the disks to you.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Since the screen on the laptop is also cracked (I used my TV as a monitor) I am just going to buy a new one rather than repairing it. I had nothing on it that I need recovered.